# Same source and destination address of captured IP-packet

Tags: c, network-programming

I have a user-space program in which I process packets. I send them there with help of iptables.

But I have a problem to get properly source and destination of the packet. The destination should be **192.168.1.66** and the source **192.168.0.102**. But the strange thing is if I write:

```
char *dstIpAddress = inet_ntoa(((struct ip*)full_packet)->ip_dst);    
char *srcIpAddress = inet_ntoa(((struct ip*)full_packet)->ip_src);
```

I get both destination and source **192.168.1.66**.
But if I write:

```
char *srcIpAddress = inet_ntoa(((struct ip*)full_packet)->ip_src);
char *dstIpAddress = inet_ntoa(((struct ip*)full_packet)->ip_dst);
```

I get both destination and source **192.168.0.102**.

Where is the problem?

Comment: That's because `inet_ntoa` returns a pointer to the same `char` array both times. Save the results in `std::string`.

Comment: Damn it, such a dump mistake and so many wasted time. Please, write your comment as answer, I'll mark it as correct answer..

Comment: [RTM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738564%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). "The string returned is guaranteed to be valid only until the next Windows Sockets function call is made within the same thread. Therefore, the data should be copied before another Windows Sockets call is made."

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. Please remove the inappropriate tag!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Captain Obvlious commented, `inet_ntoa` returns a statically allocated buffer. From [inet_ntoa(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/inet_ntoa):

> The inet_ntoa() function converts the Internet host address in, given in network byte order, to a string in IPv4 dotted-decimal notation. The string is returned in a statically allocated buffer, which subsequent calls will overwrite.

Copy the returned value or use `inet_ntop` which uses a user allocated buffer.